# Class Constructor Problems While Doing A Linear Search Across Two Classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, search, constructor

Im creating a program that is supposed have the user enter a student name and see if it exist in the student array using a linear search method. The student array is in a different class and im having trouble creating a constructor i have tried many things and its not working can someone point me in the right direction.
My linear search class is

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinearSearch {
public int find(Student [] a, String nm) {
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
if (a[i].equals(nm)){
return i;
break;
}
else{
return -1;
}
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
LinearSearch search = new LinearSearch();
Student stu = new Student();

Student [] arr = stu.getArray();
System.out.print("Enter the name to search: ");
String name = reader.nextLine();

int n = search.find(arr, name);
if ((n >= 0) && (n < arr.length)) {
System.out.println(name + " was found at index: " + n);
} else {
System.out.println(name + " was not found");
}
}
}
```

My Student class is

```
import java.util.*;

public class Student {
public Student(){

}
public Student [] getArray(){
Student [] studentArray = new Student[3];
studentArray[0] = new Student ("Mel");
studentArray[1] = new Student ("Jared");
studentArray[2] = new Student ("Mikey");
return studentArray;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined a constructor with no argument:

```
public Student() {
}
```

But you're invoking a constructor which needs a String as argument:

```
studentArray[0] = new Student("Mel");
```

So, your constructor should have a String as argument:

```
public Student(String name)
```

And you should probably store this name as a field in the Student class:

```
private String name;

public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Note that there is no way that a Student instance could be equal to a String instance. You should provide a getter method for the name, and compare the entered String with the name of the student, instead of comparing it with the student itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Student {
private String name;
public Student(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public Student [] getArray(){
Student [] studentArray = new Student[3];
studentArray[0] = new Student ("Mel");
studentArray[1] = new Student ("Jared");
studentArray[2] = new Student ("Mikey");
return studentArray;
}
  public String getName(){
      return name;
   }
}
```

and of course in the compersion you'll need to do:

```
f (a[i].getName().equals(nm)){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Student {
private String studentName;
private Student[] studentArray;

public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}

public Student[] getStudentArray() {
    return studentArray;
}

public void setStudentArray(Student[] studentArray) {
    this.studentArray = studentArray;
}

public Student(){
    studentArray = new Student[3];      
}

public Student[] getArray() {       
    Student st1 = new Student();
    st1.setStudentName("mel");
    Student st2 = new Student();
    st2.setStudentName("Jared");
    Student st3 = new Student();
    st3.setStudentName("Mikey");
    studentArray[0]=st1;
    studentArray[1]=st2;
    studentArray[2]=st3;
    return studentArray;
}
```

}

the above code is your Student class. there is no need to create a constructor though. but because you would like it i put it in the code. 
the LinearSearch class is as follow:

```
public class LinearSearch {
private int i;
public int find(Student[] a, String nm) {
    for ( i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].getStudentName().equals(nm)) {
            break;
        } else {
            i = -1;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinearSearch search = new LinearSearch();
    Student stu = new Student();

    Student[] arr = stu.getArray();
    System.out.print("Enter the name to search: ");
    String name = reader.nextLine();

    int n = search.find(arr, name);
    if ((n >= 0) && (n < arr.length)) {
        System.out.println(name + " was found at index: " + n);
    } else {
        System.out.println(name + " was not found");
    }
}
```

}